# how to move a set of filtered data to another sheet without moving filter function?

Tags: javascript, database, google-sheets

I have used the filter function =FILTER('check-in'!A8:G,'check-in'!C8:C=C4) to filter stuff from my 'check-in' sheet in my 'check-out' sheet.  I have also made my first column of 'check-out' in a way to copy the row to a sheet named 'database' once the first column of rows contain "y" (means yes). It works, but when the first row is selected (which includes the filter function), it also copies the formula, and the database sheet will not store more data after that.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  target sheet of move to named Acquired
  test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "check-out" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "y") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may copy only values:

> **[copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options)**
>
> Copies the data from a range of cells to another range of cells. By
>   default both the values and formatting are copied, but this can be
>   overridden using advanced arguments.
>
> ```
>  // The code below will copy only the values of the first 5 columns over        
>  // to the 6th column.
>  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
>  sheet.getRange("A:E").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1"), {contentsOnly:true});
>  }
> ```

in your case:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
```